# Yii CGridView - Sort by DESC first on column header click

Tags: sorting, yii, cgridview

Is it possible to change the order of a column-header click sort?

I have a "ranking" column, which upon first click will sort by ASC, and only on 2nd click would go to DESC sort - I need to reverse that so that 1st click is DESC, and 2nd click is ASC.

Is this possible?

```
return new CSqlDataProvider($sql . $search, array(
            'totalItemCount' => $itemCount,
            'params' => $params,
            'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array (
                    'enabled',
                    'store_name',
                    'rating' => array (
                        'desc' => 'rating * percent / 100 DESC',
                        'asc' => 'rating * percent / 100 ASC',
                    ),
                ),
                'defaultOrder' => array( 'store_name'=>false )
            ),
            'pagination' => array('pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize_cs', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do this is a hack that results in column arrows pointing the wrong way.

```
'desc' => 'rating * percent / 100 ASC',
'asc' => 'rating * percent / 100 DESC',
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will show the `CGridView` in descending order by default if you click the header it will display in `ASC` if u want the reverse process do it in the reverse

```
   public function search($status) 
   { 
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;    
        $criteria->order = 'store_name desc';
   }
```

Comment: This will not accomplish what OP wants. It will always sort by store_name desc.

Answer (score 0):

As of Yii 1.1.3 there was added `default` key support for attributes settings. This does exactly what you want. Example:

```
'sort' => array(
    'attributes' => array (
        'enabled',
        'store_name',
        'rating' => array (
            'desc' => 'rating * percent / 100 DESC',
            'asc' => 'rating * percent / 100 ASC',
            'default' => 'desc',
        ),
    ),
    'defaultOrder' => array( 'store_name'=>false )
),
```